# How do I make a function that works with a jquery deferred object behave like a synchronous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I have an API that returns a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) from a [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object.

The problem is that the caller is supposed to behave synchronously.  As an option to present to the team, how would I make the calling function behave synchronously?

```
var foo = function() {
     var promise = returnsPromise();
     promise.done().fail();

     // insert magic here

     // function returns when either done() or fail() is completed.
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664466/syntax-for-jquery-deferred-making-synchronous-function-return-promise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to wait for the deferred to resolve at that point, just do exactly that as you would do it without jQuery:

```
while (!promise.isResolved() && !promise.isRejected()) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in JS to create a blocking call that waits for an asynchronous result. You have to change the caller to take a callback instead

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`.always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) to execute something after the deferred object is either done or failed. it's a `"done-fail-always"`, synonymous to `"success-error-complete"` and `"try-catch-finally"`

```
var foo = function(callback) {
    var promise = returnsPromise();
    promise.done().fail().always(function(){
        //do magic
        callback();
    });
}
```

then you call foo like:

```
foo(function(){
    //the magic you want done after a done or fail
});
```

Comment: That is asynchronous. The question asks for synchronous.