# syntax for Jquery.deferred , making synchronous function return promise

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, promise

A quick question on how to use Jquery.deferred to make a slow synchronous function return a promise instead.
What I've done so far is this :

```
function sayIt(ms) {
    setTimeout( function() { console.log('what I say'); }, ms);
} 

function doIt() {
    return $.Deferred( function() { sayIt(2000); }).promise();
}


doIt().then( function() { console.log('ah'); });
```

the sayIt(2000) always goes through but the chained function after the 'then' never fires.

If I do this :

```
doIt().then( console.log('ah'));
```

the 'ah' comes up right away, and then the 'what I say' 2000ms later - what I want is of course the opposite - that after two seconds I get 'what I say' and then 'ah' right after.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: `doIt().then( console.log('ah'));` logs immediately because this executes `console.log` and then passes the return of that to `then`.

Comment: @Armatus ok thanks that makes sense, i knew the syntax of the second doIt() chain was wrong anyway. But what about the first doIt() chain? Why is doIt() not returning a promise that is resolved when sayIt(2000) returns? thanks in advance!

Comment: this isn't synchronous - the use of `setTimeout` makes it asynchronous.

Comment: @Petrov you never `resolve` the promise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To do something synchronously, but still use a promise, do:

```
function slowPromise() {

    var def = $.Deferred();

    // do something slow and synchronous
    ...

    // resolve the deferred with the result of the slow process
    def.resolve(res);

    // and return the deferred
    return def.promise();
}
```

The effect is that you still get a promise, but that promise is already resolved, so any `.then()` which is subsequently registered on it proceeds immediately.

The advantage of this pattern is that if you subsequently replace the synchronous code with something asynchronous the function still has the same external interface.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of your solution : http://jsfiddle.net/petrov/nzDae/ but it still seems to be doing the same thing - 'end' is coming before 'middle'...

Comment: i can see in the jsfiddle above that def.resolve(result) is firing right away with a still undefined 'result', because the slow function has not returned yet. the problem is that sayIt doesn't fire an event when it is finished

Comment: @Petrov "slow" is not the same as "synchronous".  You have to `resolve` the promise _at the end of the async function_.

Comment: @ Alnitak thanks for your replies. I've read up a bit more and what I really wanted to do is not possible, but your example was excellent and made me see this.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute a function after the timeout has expired, you need to call `resolve()` on the `Deferred` object from within the timeout expiration function:

```
function sayIt(ms) {
  var d = $.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('what I say');
      d.resolve()
    }, ms);
  return d;
}
```

In this way you constrain the resolution of the `Deferred` object to the expiration of the timeout.

To achieve what I believe is your intent:

```
function doIt() {
  return sayIt(2000).promise()
}
```

The `.promise()` call is optional. It only restricts the available interface for callers: by returning a `Promise` instead of the original `Deferred` object, the caller can only react to events, but not triggering them. Reference: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/.

Eventually, your original call:

```
doIt().then( function() { console.log('ah'); });
```

Will output:

```
// 2 seconds delay
what I say
ah
```