# Will deferred block the UI if used with synchronous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I just find out about the JQuery deferred object and those are very handy for chaining asychronous calls.

Knowing that [sychronous calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10664622/315493) may also be handled by deferred, I'm wondering if it's the purpose of the deferred to give the hand back to the UI after resolving each deferred or is it limited to chaining them together?

Obviously, this question is irrelevant when it comes to asynchronous calls.  What I really want to understand is the behavior of the deferred object toward the UI when it's dealing with synchronous call.

Comment: Any synchronous operation will block the UI from updating.

Comment: Let say you synchronous call take 10 seconds before having a response. For 10 seconds, the user will be unable to interact with the web site. For 10 seconds, the page display will be static. For 10 seconds, the browser will freeze. Well, for 10 seconds, the user will think it is bugged, so you should never (AFAIK) use synchronous calls.

Comment: Can you please be more specific and show a relevant code example so we can comment on a specific situation not so generally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No promise can change the amount of time that a synchronous call takes or make it so that the synchronous call does not block the browser UI.  So, if a synchronous function call takes 15 seconds to complete, the browser UI will be blocked for those 15 seconds whether using promises or not.

When using a non-jQuery, standards-compliant promises library such as Bluebird, then `.then()` handlers are always called asynchronously even if the promise was resolved synchronously.  This gives you a consistency of timing for when the `.then()` handler is called, whether it is resolved synchronously or asynchronously.  jQuery is not always standards-compliant in this way (though it apparently working on fixing this).  While this doesn't change that a 15 second synchronous function will still block the UI for 15 seconds, using a promise for a synchronous operation can sometimes change the sequencing that code executes versus not using the promises (because it's an async model, even if some of the code is sync).

Comment: What if 2 synchronous calls get chained together in jquery?  If I understand your answer, they would both lock the UI during their execution, but will the UI get the hand back between the calls?

Comment: @The_Black_Smurf - the [Promises A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) does not guarantee that the UI gets control between chained `.then()` handlers. It does guarantee that the stack should be clear, but doesn't assure that rendering or input processing can happen between chained handlers.  The implementation could use `setTimeout()` or `setImmediate()` which would likely allow servicing of input events or it could use `nextTick()` which probably would not.  Further, if it is a current version of jQuery being used, it is not spec compliant in this way and would not allow input events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Synchronous calls will block the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the UI thread, so therefore synchronous functions will take up that resource. If you want to try out some way of getting around this, you could take look at what this [site](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/javascript/ajax-async-false-freeze-ui/) has to offer. There are many other resources you could visit by using [Google](http://www.google.com).